# UIButton flip animation in for loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewanimation

My code is give below,

```
int i;
for (i=1; i < 13; i++ ){
    UIButton * myButton1 = (UIButton *)([self.view viewWithTag:i]);
    NSString *imageLoop2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr1 objectAtIndex:i-1]];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Flip" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.60];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:myButton1 cache:NO];
    myButton1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    myButton1.alpha=1.0f;
    [myButton1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageLoop2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

it flip all button in same time duration.
 
But my problem is it flip when one by one mens"first button complete flip animation then second button start flip"

please give me suggestion.

Thanx

Comment: You want all the buttons to flip at the same time?

Comment: i want first button complete flip animation then next button start flip animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imageIndex++    somewhere globally.

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled =NO;

imageIndex++;
if (imageIndex == 13){
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
    imageIndex=0;
    return;
}

 UIButton * myButton1 = (UIButton *)([self.view viewWithTag:imageIndex]);
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Flip" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.40];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:myButton1 cache:NO];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(stopButton)];


 NSString *imageLoop2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr1 objectAtIndex:imageIndex-1]];
 myButton1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
 myButton1.alpha=1.0f;
 [myButton1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageLoop2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Declare `i` somewhere globally.

```
i = 0;
[self flipNextButton];
```

Define a *flipNextButton* method like this.

```
- (void)flipNextButton {

    i++;
    if (i == 13) return;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Flip" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.60];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:myButton1 cache:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(flipNextButton);

    UIButton * myButton1 = (UIButton *)([self.view viewWithTag:i]);
    NSString *imageLoop2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr1 objectAtIndex:i-1]];
    myButton1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    myButton1.alpha=1.0f;
    [myButton1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageLoop2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to do animation one after the other in the same block.Try `[UIView setAnimationDelay:delay];`

Also keep in mind the 2 block or single block animations are performed in background thread. So with this change -

```
int i;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Flip" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
float delay = 0;
float duration = 0.6;

for (i=1; i < 13; i++ ){
    UIButton * myButton1 = (UIButton *)([self.view viewWithTag:i]);
    NSString *imageLoop2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr1 objectAtIndex:i-1]];

    [UIView setAnimationDelay:delay];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:myButton1 cache:NO];
    myButton1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    myButton1.alpha=1.0f;
    [myButton1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageLoop2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    delay = delay + duration;

}
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Also Apple Docs say that the single block animations are more smoother in terms of performance compared to the 2 block animation you are doing. Just a thought...

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Flip" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
float delay = 0;
float duration = 0.6;

for (i=1; i < 13; i++ ){
    UIButton * myButton1 = (UIButton *)([self.view viewWithTag:i]);
    NSString *imageLoop2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr1 objectAtIndex:i-1]];

    [UIView setAnimationDelay:delay];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:myButton1 cache:NO];
    myButton1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    myButton1.alpha=1.0f;
    [myButton1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageLoop2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    delay = delay + duration;

}
[UIView commitAnimations];
```